# HTML form is not taking in a date value on desktop, but is on mobile

Tags: python, html, forms, mobile, flask

I'm creating a form.  I've created a mobile block that renders on mobile and a desktop block that renders on desktop.  There are several fields in this form, and it's working fine with the exception of the date field where I want someone to put in a date.  On the mobile block, the date field is taking in a value perfectly.  On the desktop block, it is *not* taking in any value.  I end up getting this error when rendering the desktop version:

`ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'`

The HTML looks like this (I've eliminated a big chunk of the fields in the form for simplicity, let me know if you need to see more of the HTML):

```
<form method="POST">
<div class="mobile-only">
   <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2 col-lg-4">
         <label for="start-date" class="col-form-label">
            <h4>Start Date: <sup class="required">(required)</sup></h4>
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-4">
         <input type ="date" maxlength="10" class="form-control" id="start-date" name="start-date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 col-md-1">
         <button class="green-button link-text" type="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 col-md-1">
         <button class="green-button"><a href="{{ url_for('displayReminders') }}" class="link-text">Cancel</a></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The above code works fine on mobile, below is what is rendered on desktop, and gives me the above referenced error:

```
 <div class="desktop-only">
   <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-lg-1">
         <label for="start-date" class="col-form-label">
            <h4>Start Date: <sup class="required">(required)</sup></h4>
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
         <input type ="date" maxlength="10" class="form-control" id="start-date" name="start-date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 col-md-1">
         <button class="green-button link-text" type="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 col-md-1">
         <button class="green-button"><a href="{{ url_for('displayReminders') }}" class="link-text">Cancel</a></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Also, in case it's relevant, I'm using Bootstrap 4 and the backend is a Flask App with Python.  Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

your placeholder indicates to user this format:

```
placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
```

but then elsewhere in the code you are expecting:

```
format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

which is your error, if you trying to upload to database you should use YYYY-MM-DD as this is international standard, then in your front end convert to MM/DD/YYYY. 
If you asking for input of MM/DD/YYYY, you need to convert it to YYYY-DD-MM

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But then why is it working fine on the mobile div?  I'm using the same code on the mobile div.

Comment: Also, if you notice, the error is saying that there is *NO* data being registered in the field.  If it was the specific issue you were mentioning, the error would mention that data it's reading as "MM/DD/YYYY" and then say that it's not formatted properly.  I believe the '%Y', '%m', and '%d' is meant to strip the "MM", "DD", "YYYY" from the input and reformat it into the YYYY-MM-DD in my python code.  Again, this is working on mobile.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't register data because it in wrong format. Had similar issue with a webpage before, and it was my date format on windows machine causing it, had to change from European to American format.